# How to make board1[{1,1}]='X'; college work

Tags: c++

I need to make this line to work in my main function, `board1[{1,1}]='X';`.
I have no idea how to make it work. I would like to get some help please.
This is my Board class:

```
class Board {
private:
    int size;
    char** matrix = nullptr;

public: 

    Board(int sizeToSet) {                       //constructor with size
        size = sizeToSet;

        matrix = new char*[size];                 //creates a matrix
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            matrix[i] = new char[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {          //makes every cell in matix '.'
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                matrix[i][j] = '.';
            }
        }
    }

    void printSize() {                            //matrix size print
        cout << size << endl;
    }

    ~Board() {                                    //destructor
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            delete[] matrix[i];
        delete[] matrix;
    }

    Board(const Board& other) {                   //copy constructor
        size = other.size;
        matrix = new char*[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            matrix[i] = new char[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                matrix[i][j] = other.matrix[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Board& boardToPrint) {       //prints matrix
        for (int i = 0; i < boardToPrint.size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < boardToPrint.size; j++) {
                os << boardToPrint.matrix[i][j] << "  ";
            }
            os << endl;
        }
        return os;
    }
    int operator()(int row, int col) {
        cout << "it worked1" << endl;
        return 1;

    }
};
```

Comment: You would have to overload the `Board`'s `operator[]` to take in a `pair` or similar.

Comment: @ChrisMM I have no idea how to do that. I know how to overload [] and () but don't know how to use them both.

Comment: If you don't know what a pair is and can't use it a simple struct with 2 integers will work as well.

Comment: @drescherjm how can i use here a struct instead of pair class?

Answer (score 1):

Overloading the `operator[]` with a pair or similar is what you want to do

```
char & operator[]( const std::pair<size_t, size_t> &pair ) {
    return matrix[pair.first][pair.second]
}
```

Then you can call this function by doing

```
Board board1{10};
// …
board1[{0,0}] = 'X';
```

Since `std::pair` can be initialized by `{x,y}` where `x` and `y` are numbers.

Comment: Thanks! anyway i can check what i'll? like If i can get only 'X' and nothing else?

Comment: Not that I can think of in this format. You would need a function for that which validates the values.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use std::pair<> (because of an academic restriction) you could make a simple struct of your own to serve the same purpose.

```
struct mypair { int first; int second;};
```

Then add

```
char & operator[]( const mypair & st ) {
   return matrix[st.first][st.second];
}
```

and in main()

```
Board board1{10};
board1[{0,0}] = 'X';
return 0;
```

A full example is here:
https://ideone.com/mdkzM5

Or here if the link rots:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct mypair { int first; int second;}; 

class Board {
private:
    int size;
    char** matrix = nullptr;

public: 

    Board(int sizeToSet) {                       //constructor with size
        size = sizeToSet;

        matrix = new char*[size];                 //creates a matrix
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            matrix[i] = new char[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {          //makes every cell in matix '.'
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                matrix[i][j] = '.';
            }
        }
    }

    void printSize() {                            //matrix size print
        cout << size << endl;
    }

    ~Board() {                                    //destructor
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            delete[] matrix[i];
        delete[] matrix;
    }

    Board(const Board& other) {                   //copy constructor
        size = other.size;
        matrix = new char*[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            matrix[i] = new char[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                matrix[i][j] = other.matrix[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Board& boardToPrint) {       //prints matrix
        for (int i = 0; i < boardToPrint.size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < boardToPrint.size; j++) {
                os << boardToPrint.matrix[i][j] << "  ";
            }
            os << endl;
        }
        return os;
    }
    int operator()(int row, int col) {
        cout << "it worked1" << endl;
        return 1;

    }

    char & operator[]( const mypair & st ) {
        return matrix[st.first][st.second];
    }
};


int main() {
    Board board1{10};
    board1[{0,0}] = 'X';

    std::cout << board1;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It finally understand it! any chance there is a way to restrict the values that this matrix can take? I need to limit it to 'X' and 'O'. I"m not sure how to do it. can I do it this overloading '='?

Comment: @Dima • you could make `enum class XO: char { X = 'X', O = 'O' };` and change `char** matrix = nullptr;` to `XO** matrix = nullptr;` (and fix up all the ripple effects).

Comment: @Eljay Thanks again! I need it to write an error message when I try to insert something that is not 'X' or 'O'. When I use board1[{1, 4}] = 'X'; and I really have no idea how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Overload the indexing operator to take a suitable pair:

```
char& operator[](const std::pair<int, int>& xy)
{
    return matrix[xy.first][xy.second];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! anyway i can check what i'll? like If i can get only 'X' and nothing else?